# How to write a thread safe getOrCreate operation to DynamoDB without transactions?

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, thread-safety

I have 2 tables, one with a string (PK) => UUID and another with the UUID(PK) => string. The following is my use case.

1. Given the string, search for entry in first table. If UUID is there, search in second table if same entry is there or not.
2. If any of above is not true, the get operation fails and we want to try the create operation which is the following.
3. Check if there is entry in the first table again.
4. If not there, create a UUID and store it in the first table with condition primary PK doesn't exist already. Update the second table also with condition its PK doesn't exist already.
5. If it exists and there is no corresponding mapping in the second table, update the entry in first table with new UUID (no PK doesn't exist condition). Update the second table also with condition its PK doesn't exist already.
6. If it exists and there is mapping, throw illegal state exception since step 1 should have already caught this.
7. The overall API will also return the UUID.

The issue now is that during concurrent writes of same item, there is a chance that the first request will fail get, do a create and return UUID 1. The second very nearby request will also fail, do a create and return UUID 2. How to make both the requests return a single UUID? Is there any way apart from using transactions for this? Or is transactions the only and right way for this?

Comment: And why not use transactions?

Comment: This is a legacy system and I am trying to list the different approaches possible. While transactions seem ideal and long term, was checking if something like retry after worst case delay & strongly consistent read will work for short term without much code changes, hope it makes sense.

Comment: Use the ideal and long term thing.

Comment: Using transactions will be cheaper even in the short term because they're a lot less complex than any solution that you would have to come up with yourself to solve that particular problem :-)